# Some linux commands in R

Tags: r, terminal

In matlab, we could write down cd, ls to see the file and go to directory. Whether there are some similar commands in R? (easy to find the file i want)

Also, in the terminal, open filename.r could open the file, but what is the command to close the file?

Comment: In addition to `list.files` see `?files` for some control over those files. You can call all system commands through `system` or `shell`.

Answer (score 0):

there are `setwd`, `getwd` and `list.files`

Comment: how to open a .r file with